# Есть ли функция в С++, которая определяет, есть ли заданный элемент в векторе?

Tags: c++, алгоритм, вектор

Есть ли функция в С++, которая определяет, есть ли заданный элемент в векторе?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Такие задачи решаются с помощью стандартных алгоритмов, объявленных в заголовке `<algorithm>,` таких, как

```
std::find
std::find_if
std::find_if_not
std::find_end
std::find_first_of
std::adjacent_find
std::search
std::search_n
```

Если вектор отсортирован, то вы также можете воспользоваться алгоритмами на основе двоичного поиска, такими как

```
std::binary_search
std::lower_bound
std::upper_bound
std::equal_range
```

Вот простейшая демонстрационная программа

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <vector>

int main() 
{
    const int N = 10;

    std::vector<int> v( N );

    std::srand( ( unsigned int )std::time( nullptr ) );

    std::generate( v.begin(), v.end(), [=] { return std::rand() % N; } );

    for ( int x : v ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        if ( std::find( v.begin(), v.end(), i ) != v.end() )
        {
            std::cout << i << " is present in the vector" << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << i << " is not present in the vector" << std::endl;
        }           
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::sort( v.begin(), v.end() );

    for ( int x : v ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        if ( std::binary_search( v.begin(), v.end(), i ) )
        {
            std::cout << i << " is present in the vector" << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << i << " is not present in the vector" << std::endl;
        }
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Ее вывод на консоль может выглядеть следующим образом:

```
6 1 4 6 2 6 6 2 6 7 
0 is not present in the vector
1 is present in the vector
2 is present in the vector
3 is not present in the vector
4 is present in the vector
5 is not present in the vector
6 is present in the vector
7 is present in the vector
8 is not present in the vector
9 is not present in the vector

1 2 2 4 6 6 6 6 6 7 
0 is not present in the vector
1 is present in the vector
2 is present in the vector
3 is not present in the vector
4 is present in the vector
5 is not present in the vector
6 is present in the vector
7 is present in the vector
8 is not present in the vector
9 is not present in the vector
```

Answer (score 3):

А как же. `find` или `find_if`.

```
if (find(v.begin(),v.end(),val) != v.end()) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
template<class T>
bool contains(const std::vector<T>& arr, const T& value) {
    return std::cend(arr) != std::find(cbegin(arr), cend(arr), value);
}
```